# Show that $f$ is bounded.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Show that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b].$

We are supposed to use intermediate value theorem for this problem. But, I don't understand how to approach. All I can do is let, $$g(x) = f(x) - x$$  Then, $$g(a) = f(a)-a < 0$$ and $$g(b) = f(b) - b >0$$ And, according to I.V.T, $\exists c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $g(c ) = 0$. Now what? How can I connect all these? I am clueless here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need something more than intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't supposed to use the *Extreme* Value Theorem?

Comment: Also, how did you decide that $g(a)<0$ and $g(b)>0$? There's no reason to suspect that's true.

Comment: I assumed that from the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem does not tell you that! There's an exercise, which I did in my analysis class, and said if $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)<a$ and $f(b)>b$, then $f$ has a fixed point. The answer is almost the one you gave!

Comment: Oh! I am all confused here. This was given as an exercise after we've finished our intermediate value theorem lecture in class. Therefore, I assumed the problem has to do with the I.V.T.

Comment: @CameronBuie Maybe you're right. Maybe this is a question for the Extreme value theorem since we'll go over on that next. But not sure though!

Comment: What is $M$ ...?

Comment: @zhw. $M$ is just a number that is $> 0$

Comment: I know, but it reads weird. Better to say "Show $f$ is bounded."

Comment: Like others have mentioned in comment this is totally different from IVT. This statement is usually proven using "completeness of real numbers" and "definition of continuity". You can see a lot of such proofs (based on equivalent formulations of completeness of real numbers) at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-boundedness-property.html

Answer (score 3):

Assume a function $f(x)$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$. We prove it is not continuous.Then, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $(x_{n}) \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_{n})>n$. Now extract a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ of $x_{n}$ converging to $x \in [a,b]$ (Bolzano Weirstrass and $[a,b]$ is closed). So $f(x_{n_{k}}) > n_{k}$. Now take $k \to \infty$. By comaraison, the sequence $(f(x_{n_{k}}))$ diverges. The sequential criterion for continuity is not satisfied!.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the fact that continuous functions map compact sets onto compact sets.  Since $[a,b]$ is compact, $f([a,b])$ is compact and hence closed and bounded.

Comment: Its better if you use a contrapositive argument or not using topology like compactness.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess that you are mixing up related concepts. The proof that a continuous function $f$ is bounded on a compact interval $[a,b]$ most naturally uses the definition of continuity and the definition of compactness, and various properties of how compactness is preserved under continuous maps.

This has little to do with the intermediate value theorem (which is all about connectedness and continuous maps).